# Extracting last word from many data frame columns (R)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains a 3 columns. The data looks like this

```
V1                V2               V3
Auto = Chevy      Engine = V6      Trans = Auto
Auto = Chevy      Engine = V8      Trans = Manual
Auto = Chevy      Engine = V10     Trans = Manual
```

I want the dataframe to look like this:

```
Auto       Engine  Trans
Chevy      V6      Auto
Chevy      V8      Manual
Chevy      V10     Manual
```

In other words, retrieve the last string after the "=" and take the 1st value in the column and make it the column header. Or a way to just retrieve the last word of after the "=" and replace it the column without adding new columns.

Can this be done in R? Many thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, _none_ of us asked you what you tried and what didn't work. +1 for getting us to all the work.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you don't mind just using old-style (pre-Hadley) R, here's a solution:

```
> x <- as.data.frame(list(c('Auto = Chevy', 'Auto = Chevy', 'Auto = Chevy'),
+ c('Engine = V6', 'Engine = V8', 'Engine = V10'),
+ c('Trans = Auto', 'Trans = Manual', 'Trans = Manual')),
+ stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> values <- lapply(x, gsub, pattern='.*= ', replacement='')
> new.names <- lapply(x, gsub, pattern=' =.*', replacement='')
> new.names <- lapply(new.names, unique)
> names(values) <- new.names
> new.frame <- as.data.frame(values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> new.frame
   Auto Engine  Trans
1 Chevy     V6   Auto
2 Chevy     V8 Manual
3 Chevy    V10 Manual
```

It won't work for a data frame with many columns, but it will work for a narrow data frame with many rows.

Comment: I do want to call out the use of the 'embedded parameter' metaphor in the calls to `lapply`. The `apply` functions all take an ellipsis of named parameters which are then passed to the function inside the implicit loop.  In this case, the parameters `pattern` and `replacement` are added to the inner calls to `gsub`, which is how the `lapply` calls actually work -- they aren't actually black magic.

Comment: I've had students and colleagues who've looked at that kind of code and asked "how does `gsub` get its other parameters"? So, evidently, there are folks for whom it's black magic.

Answer (score 4):

Or, we could avoid the `stringr` crutch and use a highly optimized function for just such this use case in `stringi` (most of `stringr` functions wrap `stringi` functions):

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)

read.table(text='V1,V2,V3
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V6","Trans = Auto"
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V8","Trans = Manual"
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V10","Trans = Manual"',
sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

mutate_all(df, funs(stri_extract_last_words))
##      V1  V2     V3
## 1 Chevy  V6   Auto
## 2 Chevy  V8 Manual
## 3 Chevy V10 Manual
```

More representative tidyverse with the "column name" req that could actually break your R script if the columns aren't as you imagine:

```
library(stringi)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

read.table(text='V1,V2,V3
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V6","Trans = Auto"
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V8","Trans = Manual"
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V10","Trans = Manual"',
sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

mutate_all(df, funs(stri_extract_last_words)) %>%
  setNames(mutate_all(df, stri_extract_first_words) %>%
             distinct() %>%
             flatten_chr())
```

More tidyverse and `stringi` with the very much assumed requirements that could actually break your R script if the columns aren't as you imagine:

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)

read.table(text='V1,V2,V3
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V6","Trans = Auto"
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V8","Trans = Manual"
"Auto = Chevy","Engine = V10","Trans = Manual"',
sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) -> df

by_row(df, function(x) {
  map(x, stri_match_all_regex, "(.*) = (.*)") %>%
    map(1) %>%
    map(~setNames(.[,3], .[,2])) %>%
    flatten_df()
}) %>%
  select(.out) %>%
  unnest()
## # A tibble: 3 × 3
##    Auto Engine  Trans
##   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
## 1 Chevy     V6   Auto
## 2 Chevy     V8 Manual
## 3 Chevy    V10 Manual
```

Comment: And, if the first word happens to differ, then what? Unless I can't read English the OP said _'Or a way to just retrieve the last word of after the "="'_ and if the OP can't set `colnames()` there are far worse issues at hand.

Comment: Perhaps if the OP provided representative data of the diversity it'd be easier to make the example

Answer (score 3):

We can do this with `base R` only options

**1)** Using `scan` and `sub` - Remove the substring `=` followed by white space with `sub` after converting `data.frame` to `matrix`, then use `scan` to return a `vector` of words.  Based on the recycling of logical vector (`c(FALSE, TRUE)`), we get the alternating words in 'v1' and assign the output to 'df2' while we change the column names with the `unique` elements of alternate values extracted from 'v1' using `c(TRUE, FALSE)` as logical recycling `vector`.

```
df2 <- df1
v1 <- scan(text=sub("=\\s+", "", as.matrix(df1)), what="", sep=" ", quiet=TRUE)
df2[] <- v1[c(FALSE, TRUE)]
colnames(df2) <- unique(v1[c(TRUE, FALSE)])
df2
#   Auto Engine  Trans
#1 Chevy     V6   Auto
#2 Chevy     V8 Manual
#3 Chevy    V10 Manual
```

**2)**  Using `sub` - Extract the last word by capturing it as a group and replacing it with the backreference (`\\1`) after looping through the columns (`lapply(df1, ..`)

```
df2[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) sub(".*\\b(\\w+)$", "\\1", x))
```

**3)**  Using `strsplit` - Split the string by delimiter (`"=\\s+`) and get the last element (`tail, 1`) while looping through the columns as in **2)**

```
df2[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) sapply(strsplit(x, "=\\s+"), tail, 1))
```

We change the columns in 2nd and 3rd solutions by extracting the first word with `sub` on the `unlist`ted first row

```
colnames(df2) <- sub("\\s+=.*", "", unlist(df1[1,], use.names = FALSE))
```

---

Or other options are based on package solutions

**1)** Using `str_extract` - Extract the word (`\\w+`) before the end `$` of the string by looping over the columns with `lapply` and assign the `list` output to a copy of the original dataset ('df2').  Then, we change the column name, by extracting the first word using `sub` on the `unlist`ed first row of original dataset.

```
library(stringr)
df2[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) str_extract(x, "\\w+$"))
colnames(df2) <- word(unlist(df1[1,]), 1)
df2
#   Auto Engine  Trans
#1 Chevy     V6   Auto
#2 Chevy     V8 Manual
#3 Chevy    V10 Manual
```

**2)** Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(df1) %>% 
      separate(value, into = c("header", "value")) %>%
      group_by(key) %>%
      mutate(i1 = row_number()) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      select(-key) %>% 
      spread(header, value) %>%
      select(-i1)
# A tibble: 3 × 3
#   Auto Engine  Trans
#* <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1 Chevy     V6   Auto
#2 Chevy     V8 Manual
#3 Chevy    V10 Manual
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("Auto = Chevy", "Auto = Chevy", "Auto = Chevy"
), V2 = c("Engine = V6", "Engine = V8", "Engine = V10"), V3 = c("Trans = Auto", 
"Trans = Manual", "Trans = Manual")), .Names = c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```